# Python: how to add missing values to index and columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
df
    2    4   5
0   1    3   2 
3  -1    4   5
5   3   -6   7
```

I want to fill the missing values in the index and in the columns and fill the values with zeros, so that:

```
df
    0   1   2   3   4    5
0   0   0   1   0   3    2 
1   0   0   0   0   0    0
2   0   0   0   0   0    0
3   0   0  -1   0   4    5
4   0   0   0   0   0    0
5   0   0   3   0  -6    7
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `np.arange`:

```
df = (df.reindex(index = np.arange(df.index.max() + 1), 
                columns = np.arange(df.columns.max() + 1), 
                fill_value=0))
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  0  1  0  3  2
1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0 -1  0  4  5
4  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  3  0 -6  7
```